# TideKit Desktop Scripting functionality

Tags: tidekit

So, I understand the concept of TideKit (and TideSDK) of packaging a database, and native functionality (such as file system manipulation) through the TI interface into what otherwise would be a (potentially offline) web-app.

I'm confused as to how deep or powerful server side scripting integration goes with the desktop app?

**To the point** for a potential use case of mine: **could I package complex server-side scripting tasks** like video compression/encoding/manipulation into my HTML app, so that when that is packaged as a desktop app, the client's desktopp app is capable of running those tasks itself via the packaged executable, **without needing any extra software on the client side** (python / node / whatever server side scripting language) ?

Comment: TideKit does not exist any more, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28204167/3737186)